# Visual Studio , SQL Server can't connect properly

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I am new to visual studio (2010) environment. I want to make an application in asp.net which requires database connection with MS SQL SERVER 2012( SQL Server Management Studio).

In "Add Connection" Wizard , I am specifying the database details and it is successfully connecting , but it is just displaying the "System Databases" , i.e. not displaying the databases I created.

I think there is some permissions problem.Thanks in advance for the help.

Fixed it by replacing the corrupted dll located here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\dsref80.dll"

[dsref80.dll](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=781318cea9a1daf6&id=781318CEA9A1DAF6%21107)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this problem.

I did the following:

In the Server Explorer, I right clicked the Data Connections, chose "Add Connection..." and created a Microsoft SQL Server. I set the server name to .\SQLEXPRESS and the database name to Library.
I then added the following to app.config: It seems to work now.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Library"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=true;" />
</connectionStrings>
```